# How to extract info from the facebook friends request to an array of ID's in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, parse-platform

I am making an app where I do a call for the users friends, to see if they are using the application as well. This gives back the following response from Facebook:

```
    {
    data =     (
                {
            id = 144706239251534;
            name = "Patricia Alaacfdgiigah Chengsen";
        },
                {
            id = 117830675674886;
            name = "James Alaadchdcidfe Qinstein";
        }
    );
    paging =     {
        next = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/102147933512016/friends?format=json&locale=en_US&access_token=CAACoIuVy9IEBALQwZCoH9oOvzNUNTBxQou93d1fmP4MssZAP4lfsZBHi982DadRgtgM3tj2JJNpDA0F8JjFrSQrK5LPZA24n01xVyZBV3agCd8xWWLkdZChi16GEFaeO4BHdOaA0iQHOQ7k7DZAq8UdRCEpzSXEdtVZBByFRAzz2gFPSJAumfqsTVVzkDkAbgo6NnEZBk1kSKZAmYGSKvFGBmE4fDVKvkbYtHGpha0i8vOnAZDZD&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=enc_AdDMBziLTzrrGBpWpn68ZCuDSqkYjAKQoUUsj4HCA4mlSrUXjIBUx6TJZCC5TnoNkLjR9IkAXw0i7VZBf6NgvNAo2An";
    };
    summary =     {
        "total_count" = 2;
    };
}
```

I want to 'parse' this, and put the id's in an array, but I don't really know where to begin. Is this considered a JSON? (I do not think so, since the `[ ]` are missing) or a Dictionary? (Also unsure since is uses `=` instead of `:` )

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store result as NSDictionary. If you look in Facebooks SDK docs, there is some code you can use, for example I am using this for Registration with Facebook:

```
if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
                    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                        if (error == nil){
                            NSLog("Dict: %@", result as! NSDictionary)
```

Result is stored as NSDictionary which later you can use by calling objectForKey. For example, get user name and last name from result:

```
let firstName = self.dict.objectForKey("first_name") as! String
let lastName = self.dict.objectForKey("last_name") as! String
```

Comment: Thanks, your comment got me further. At least now I know what to do.